# If Else on one line getting condition expression error

Tags: python, tkinter

Any ideas why this line isn't working?  I want a variable to be assigned the integer of the text in a label. If the label does not have any text assigned, I want the variable to equal 0.

I'm getting a "can't assign to conditional expression" error before it even tries to run.

```
var = int(label.cget("text")) if label.cget("text") != "" else var = 0
```

Comment: ...`else 0`. remove `var =`, you've already got that at the beginning of the line.

Comment: This is called the ternary operator (or conditional expression) and only takes expressions `expr if expr else expr`, and assignment is a statement in python unlike some other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More pythonic:

```
var = int(label.cget("text") or 0)
```